# AWS EBS Volume does not mount, but no error message

Tags: amazon-web-services, mount

I'm unable to mount an AWS EBS Volume. Name is xvdf. Mountpoint is /home/ubuntu/disk1. The mount command produces no error. But it does not work.

Why the mount command does not mount my volume? And why the command doesn't tell me, why he does not mount?

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-142:~$ rm -rf  /home/ubuntu/disk1  # make things clear
ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-142:~$ mkdir  /home/ubuntu/disk1   # create mountpoint
ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-142:~$  lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0    8G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0    8G  0 part /
xvdf    202:80   0  100G  0 disk
ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-142:~$ sudo mount /dev/xvdf /home/ubuntu/disk1
ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-142:~$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0    8G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0    8G  0 part /
xvdf    202:80   0  100G  0 disk
ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-142:~$ uname -a
Linux ip-172-31-19-142 4.4.0-1044-aws #53-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 11 13:49:57 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-142:~$
```

The volume to be mounted looks fine:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-142:~$ sudo file -s /dev/xvdf
/dev/xvdf: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=badc7d94-316e-409e-b2f3-619a621ae5a2 (extents) (large files) (huge files)
```

with best regards,
Irv

Comment: Have you edited the /etc/fstab file with the information about major filesystems on the system?

Answer (score 11):

In my case this happened because I had a wrong UUID in `/etc/fstab`:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   defaults,discard    0 0
UUID=8ec04604-0e23-42d4-967e-a120f65fe4e7  /data  ext4  defaults,nofail 0 2
$ ls -la /dev/disk/by-uuid/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 80 Jan 12 17:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 80 Jan 12 17:50 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Jan 12 17:50 4e13556e-d28d-407b-bcc6-97160eafebe1 -> ../../xvda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jan 12 17:50 b9b18cb2-9d7e-43ac-9f79-794846595e9e -> ../../xvdf
```

This caused that

```
$ sudo mount -v /dev/xvdf /data
```

failed silently. The strange thing is that you can mount the filesystem without problems on another mountpoint, which is not used in `/etc/fstab`:

```
$ sudo mkdir /data2
$ sudo mount -v /dev/xvdf /data2
```

But the real fix is to fix the wrong UUID in /etc/fstab

```
$ sudo nano /etc/fstab
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   defaults,discard    0 0
UUID=b9b18cb2-9d7e-43ac-9f79-794846595e9e  /data  ext4  defaults,nofail 0 2
```

After doing this I was able to mount the filesystem again at `/data`.

It can also be useful to have a look at the logfiles

```
$ less /var/log/syslog
```

[Other people](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1741#issuecomment-227238380) are suggesting to also run

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

to make `mount` work again.

Comment: Strange, like you I can mount to another folder not specified by /etc/fstab, but the UUID is correct.

Comment: I just removed the entry from the file, rebooted and then mounted again on the original desired folder, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had edited the /etc/fstab file.
And I made a wrong entry.
This resulted in the behaviour given above.

I had checked the /etc/fstab file doing a "mount -a".
The were no erros, so I thought, everything was fine.
But that is not correct.
The mounting failed without an error on the commandline.
I could find the error in the logfiles.

Thank you, lft93ryt, for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a file system with mkfs to mount the file system.

Try making a file system with `mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdf` update it in the /etc/fstab and then mount it.